# Resolving symlinks of a file path using boost c++11

Tags: c++11, boost, symlink

I am trying to resolve any symlinks present in a file path even if the symlink is occurred to the parent directory of a file.

So if for example I have `a/b/d/file` and a symlink is created for dir b where b -> c so the file path is `a/c/d/file`.

Is there a function that could detect this symlink of the file a/c/d/file and return it to `a/b/d/file`?

I am using c++11

I tried the lexically.normal() function but isn’t working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canonical()`. If (parts of) the path doesn't exist, use `weakly_canonical()`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a90e5141c3a0897b)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::filesystem::path;

#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
static void touch(path p) { boost::filesystem::ofstream(p).flush(); }

int main() {
    std::cout << std::unitbuf << std::boolalpha;

    path const a = "./a/";
    std::cout << "Cleaned up: " << remove_all(a) << std::endl;

    create_directories(a / "c" / "d");
    create_directory_symlink("c", a / "b");

    for (path const l : {"a/b/d/file", "a/c/d/file", "a/./b/d/../d/file"}) {
        std::cout << "----\n";
        if (exists(l)) remove(l);
        std::cout << l << " exists: " << exists(l) << std::endl;

        // If (parts of) path does not exist, only weakly_canonical available:
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            canonical(l, ec);
            std::cout << " canonical() returns " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            std::cout << " weakly_canonical() returns relative " << relative(weakly_canonical(l))
                      << std::endl;
            std::cout << " weakly_canonical() returns " << weakly_canonical(l) << std::endl;
        }

        // If path exists, all operations available
        touch(l); // make sure it exists
        std::cout << l << " exists: " << exists(l) << std::endl;
        std::cout << l << " refers to relative " << relative(canonical(l)) << std::endl;
        std::cout << l << " refers to " << canonical(l) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]